# Angular dependency registration token type

Tags: angular

Instead of using string-token in the example below, I want to know how to use type-token to register the dependency, because the dependency is represented by a class? In the following example, `service` can easily be substituted through `useClass` configuration option from one class to another (HeroService <-> NewheroService).

How to rewrite this example that the parameter of HeroListComponent constructor looks like `constructor( private service: MyService)`? I tried to create interface class MyService,  where HeroService and NewheroService inherits from. Also changed provider from `'MyService'` to `MyService` but it throws an error:

> 'MyService' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {}

@Injectable()
export class NewheroService {}
```

hero.component.ts:

```
@Component({ ..., 
  providers: [{
    provide: 'MyService',
    useClass: HeroService
  }]
})
export class HeroListComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('MyService') private service: any) { }
}
```

Comment: `MyService` is most likely an interface in your case. The problem is interfaces does not exist on runtime. you could have used `MyService` if it was a class

Comment: @Andrei If I would define an abstract class instead interface  and extend both services from that class, then it will work?

Comment: yes, shoud work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a general service.

```
export class GeneralService {
  //  Can be defined common methods or properties here
}
```

Then your services extends it:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService extends GeneralService {
 constructor(){super();}
}

@Injectable()
export class NewheroService extends GeneralService {
 constructor(){super();}
}
```

Then in your component you can inject it like this:

```
@Component({ ..., 
  providers: [{
    provide: GeneralService,
    useClass: HeroService
  }]
})
export class HeroListComponent {
  constructor(private service: GeneralService) { }
}
```

The `GeneralService` can be injected into other components or services, and Angular's dependency injection will provide the instance of `HeroService` wherever the interface is used.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-injection-e7s4k2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero.service.ts

Comment: [_The problem is interfaces does not exist on runtime._](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76528870/angular-dependency-registration-token-type#comment134936393_76528870)

Comment: @Hölderlin my bad, updated the answer, it should be a class.

Answer (score 1):

That's the main use of [injection tokens](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) : you have already used them in the past if you have used angular material's dialog (`MAT_DIALOG_DATA`)

```js
const MY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<string>('Some unique identifier');

@Component({ ..., 
  providers: [{
    provide: MY_SERVICE,
    useClass: HeroService
  }]
})
export class HeroListComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MY_SERVICE) private service: any) { }
}
```

Comment: Is injection- and string-tokens principle similar, where main difference is the unique identifier, so that last registered token doesn't overwrites all previously registered tokens with the same name?

Comment: The purpose is similar, but the mechanic isn't : string injection is on equality, while injection tokens use a weakmap (Google it), making it unique even if you don't provide a unique identifier